# How do I get the CanXXX behavior for drop down selection in Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

If I have a button named Execute, I can write a method to control that button's clickability:

```
public bool CanExecute()
{
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SelectedCatalogName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.selectedCommandName);
}
```

Similarly, I have a dropdown named SelectedCommand which should be disabled until another dropdown is selected:

```
private BindableCollection<string> catalogNames;
public BindableCollection<string> CatalogNames
{
    get
    {
        return this.catalogNames;
    }
}

private string selectedCatalog;
public string SelectedCatalogName
{
    get
    {
        return this.selectedCatalog;
    }
    set
    {
        this.selectedCatalog = value;
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SelectedCatalogName);
    }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
// --> Can I do this or the equivalent?
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
public bool CanSelectCatalogName()
{
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SelectedCatalogName);
}
```

Note: question in comments above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no inbuilt convention to support this but you can just do a simple binding:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SelectedCatalog" IsEnabled="{Binding CanSelectCatalogName}" />
```

Comment: thanks, but now i'm slightly confused as to why the convention for buttons exists if that's all it takes (i'm sure there's a reason, i just don't see it yet)

Comment: i suspect because Caliburn Micro was supplanting the ICommand functionality, which handled the Execute()/ CanExecute() pattern.